# Server-side rendering and client-side rendering. Is my understanding correct?

Tags: javascript, java, web, architecture, software-design

I have implemented two browser based pages, which populates country names in a select tag.
The first approach is server-side rendering using java, jsp. Please follow the code below.

CountryBean.java

```
package com.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class CountryBean implements Serializable{
    private int countryId;
    private String countryName;
    
    public CountryBean(int countryId, String countryName) {
        this.countryId = countryId;
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    public int getCountryId() {
        return countryId;
    }

    public void setCountryId(int countryId) {
        this.countryId = countryId;
    }

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }   
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int num = this.countryId * 31;
        num *= 11 * this.countryName.hashCode();
        return num;
    }
}
```

ServersideRendering.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="com.bean.CountryBean" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>

<%! List<CountryBean> countrylist = null; %>

<%
    countrylist = new ArrayList<CountryBean>();
    countrylist.add(new CountryBean(100,"Saudi Arabia"));
    countrylist.add(new CountryBean(101,"South Africa"));
    countrylist.add(new CountryBean(102,"South Korea"));
    countrylist.add(new CountryBean(103,"South Sudan"));
    countrylist.add(new CountryBean(104,"Singapore"));
    countrylist.add(new CountryBean(105,"Somalia"));
    countrylist.add(new CountryBean(106,"Sweden"));
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Server-side Loading</title>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="center">Countries</td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control">
                                <%for(CountryBean countryBean : countrylist){%>
                                    <option value='<%=countryBean.getCountryId()%>'><%=countryBean.getCountryName()%></option>
                                <%} %>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

The second approach is client-side rendering where its just html,css,javascript to populate the data in select tag, the code is as follows,

ClientsideRendering.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Client-side rendering</title>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javaScript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var countryList = [
                    { "countryName" : "Saudi Arabia", "countryId" : "100" },
                    { "countryName" : "South Africa", "countryId" : "101" },
                    { "countryName" : "South Korea", "countryId" : "102" },
                    { "countryName" : "South Sudan", "countryId" : "103" },
                    { "countryName" : "Singapore", "countryId" : "104" },
                    { "countryName" : "Somalia", "countryId" : "105" },
                    { "countryName" : "Sweden", "countryId" : "106" }
                ];
                
                var optionText = "";
                
                $.each(countryList,function(index, countryObject){
                    optionText += `<option value='${countryObject.countryId}'>${countryObject.countryName}</option>`;
                }); 
                
                $("#countries").append(`${optionText}`);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="center">Countries</td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control" id="countries"></select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

According to my understanding in server-side rendering I am just writing the HTML pre-loaded with data in request.

Where as in client-side I just dynamically write the data in html.

Is my understanding correct ?

In which cases I need to go with server-side rendering and when should I go with client-side rendering.

What about data sensitive websites like banking and financial services websites, in those cases which will be prefered ?

Comment: Usually you'd have the data coming from a database and query on the database.  In the code you post above you would expose the dataset in the javascript example and not in the server-side example.  However, most sites would make an "ajax" call to return data from database when using javascript.  The advantage of using a Javascript "ajax" call is you don't have to wait for a page load and you can update only the parts of the page that you need to update.  (It's quicker and more flexible.)  Security measures are basically the same for either method.

Comment: The database queries will always be run server-side.  When retrieving data via Javascript the server-side code returns data to the javascript via a "callback".